# Computing Linear Congruence -Uncertainty Of Answer

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

given:
 $$17x\equiv 3\pmod{2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7}$$

after extended euclidean algorithm of $(17,210)$ I got:

$$1=3\cdot210+17\cdot(-37)$$ now multplying both RHS and LHS by $3$ I get :

$$210\cdot9+17\cdot(-111)=3$$

then, doing (mod $210$) for both sides I get:

$$17\cdot(-111)\equiv 3\pmod{210}$$

so the answer supposed to be $-111$ but the answer is $99$ for $X.$

My question: is it valid to add $210$ just to $-111$ without the all exp. which is $17(-111)$?

Comment: $99 \equiv -111 \bmod 210$. Since $(17, 210) = 1$ you can divide both sides of the congruence by $17$ to see this.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why dividing both sides by 17 is congruent to each other. I get that -111+210=99. But why is the division applies here? and how? I seem to get different answers mod 210. one is 14 and the other is -9.

Answer (score 1):

For some modulus $m>0$, the residue class of $a$ modulo $m$ is the set of integers $x$ such that
$$x\equiv a\pmod{m}$$
You may see this set denoted $\widehat{a}$, $[a]$, or $\bar{a}$ in various texts. Hence $\widehat{a}=a+mq$, where $q=0,\pm1,\pm2,\dotsc$. Note the numbers $0,1,2,\dotsc,m-1$ are incongruent modulo $m$ and so the $m$ residue classes $\widehat{0},\widehat{1},\widehat{2},\dotsc,\widehat{m-1}$ are disjoint with their union being the whole of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Any set of $m$ integers incongruent modulo $m$ is termed a *complete residue system*, and as such each representative comes from a distinct residue class $\widehat{0},\widehat{1},\widehat{2},\dotsc,\widehat{m-1}$. We see $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots,209\}$ is a complete residue system mod $210$, as is $\{1,2,3,\ldots,210\}$.

Now since $99\equiv -111\pmod{210}$, $-111$ and $99$ belong in the *same* residue class and we can say $\widehat{99}=\widehat{-111}$. Note $\widehat{99}=99+210\cdot q$ where $q=0,\pm1,\pm2,\dotsc$, and so we can extend this (infinitely) to generate the whole residue class $\widehat{99}$:
$$\widehat{99}=\widehat{-111}=\widehat{309}=\widehat{-321},\dotsc$$
Note we could now go on to do this for all the other $209$ residue classes, and this would give us $210$ infinite sets of numbers whose union is $\mathbb{Z}$. Note if the modulus is a prime $p$, the residue classes modulo $p$ form a field. As such every element $a$ in a complete residue system, disregarding $0$, has a multiplicative inverse $a^{-1}$. In such a case

Note that if $\gcd(a,m)=1$, then the linear congruence 
$$a\cdot x \equiv b \pmod{m}$$
has a unique solution $b$.

Hence due to $\gcd(17,210)=1$ your solution will be unique. This also means you can divide through by $17$ in the congruence to give
$$x\equiv \frac{3}{17}\equiv3\cdot17^{-1}\equiv3\cdot173\equiv99\pmod{210}$$
Here $17^{-1}\equiv173\pmod{210}$, or multiplying through by $17$ we get
$$17\cdot173\equiv1\pmod{210}$$
We call $17$ and $173$ modular inverses of each other as their product is $1$ modulo $210$. (This is how division works in congruences, you have to think in terms of inverses.)

One way of finding these modular inverses is the extended Euclidean algorithm:
\begin{align*}
210&=12\cdot17+6\\
17&=2\cdot6+5\\
6&=1\cdot5+1
\end{align*}
so, working backwards
\begin{align*}
1&=6-1\cdot5=6-1\cdot(17-2\cdot6)=3\cdot6-1\cdot17\\
&=3\cdot(210-12\cdot17)-1\cdot17\\
&=3\cdot210-37\cdot17
\end{align*}
So looking mod $210$ we get
$$3\cdot210-37\cdot17\equiv0-37\cdot17\equiv173\cdot 17\equiv1\pmod{210}$$
because modulo $210$, $\widehat{-37}=\widehat{173}$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $111+99=210,$ you have $99\equiv -111 \bmod 210,$ so $-111$ is the same as $99.$ If an assigned exercise requires a number in the set $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots,209\},$ then $-111$ would be wrong, but it's not incorrect to say that $-111$ belongs to the congruence class that you're looking for.

You shouldn't be calling the same thing both $x$ and $X;$ you can use one or the other.

Comment: Ok I understand. by the way can fully explain what it means congruence class. can 2 classes be equal to each other?